# Loading textures with GLKTextureLoader seems to waste CPU memory?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, memory-leaks

In our game app, it is very important to use textures without pre-multiplied alpha. Hence, for loading textures, as suggested in Apple guidelines, we use the `GLKTextureLoader`.

**Method 1:**

```
...
GLKTextureInfo* pTextureInfo = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfFile:pPath options:pTextureOptions error:&pError];
...
```

In the options we can turn off premultiplied alpha and everything is fine, but there seems to be a huge memory problem!

In comparison, we can load textures by using UIImage and CoreGraphics stuff, but then pre-multiplied alpha problem remains. The nice thing here is that we have more control and can easily release pixel data from CPU memory after passing it to the GPU via `glTexImage2D(…):`

**Method 2:**

```
...
uint8_t* pixelData = loadImageDataWithUIImageAndCoreGraphics(…);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelData);
delete[] pixelData;
...
```

When loading textures with **Method 1** Xcode shows memory consumption of 80MB, by using **Method 2** we have memory consumption of only 55MB. If we now create memory leaks by not deleting pixel data (remove the line "delete[] pixelData" in **Method 2**) then memory consumption is also by about 80MB.

Hence, it seems as though `GLTextureLoader` does not release image/pixel data from CPU memory after passing it to the GPU. Why not? Is there a way to do it manually? How to avoid this huge additional (and unnecessary) memory consumption?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!